# Adding an include directory to all configurations in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I was trying to add a directory as an include which contains all the header files and resides in the same project folder. I encountered an option saying "add to all configurations". What is this option supposed to do ? Would checking it mean that, that directory would automatically get included in all future projects ?

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owqrn.png) is what I am talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it just means all configurations for the current project. A configuration in this context is something like "Debug" or "Release" (you can also create additional ones). See the "Configuration" drop-down box visible in your screenshot (in the parent dialog).